# Kotlin Hibernate @ManyToOne MERGE violates foreign key constraint (Postgres)

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, thymeleaf, many-to-one, constraintviolationexception

I implemented a @ModelToOne Relationship and would like to use a Dropdown List via Thymeleaf. I use a separate formular to persist PlaceEntities and a formular for WorkEntities where a appropriate Place can be selected from the mentioned dropdown list. The current implementation forces me to add a Place, otherwise a WorkEntity will not be persisted. When I try to save the form without having selected a Place from the dropdown list the following Error appears:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "work" violates foreign key constraint "fklyi06ir16ujsbylbtf5k33rmv"
> Detail: Key (place_of_premiere_id)=() is not present in table "place".

I already tried to add the "optional = true" condition (which is true by default in any case) or @JoinColumn(nullable = true) to the @ManyToOne Side but none of these worked.

Saving the form with a selected Place works like a charm but how can I do this if I want to persist a WorkEntity without a PlaceEntity (which means that the foreignkey column must be null)?

EDIT:
I could solve this problem by myself. The error came from the th:value="" in the first option tag of my template. Instead of null it creates a zero args Object of Place which cannot be persisted. I put an if statement in my controller which might be not the most elegant approach but I do not know how to make a th:value= nullable in Thymeleaf.

My fixed Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/addWork"])
fun addWork(@Validated work: Work?, bindingResult: BindingResult): String {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        print(bindingResult.allErrors)
    }
    
    work?.apply {

        if (placeOfPremiere?.id == "") {
            this.placeOfPremiere = null
        }
    }

    workService.create(work!!)
    return "editor/addWork"
}
```

Abstract class for all Entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Entity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    open var id: String?,
    open var title: String?,
    open var created: OffsetDateTime,
    open var modified: OffsetDateTime
```

Child:

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "work")
     class WorkEntity(
             id: String? = null,
             title: String? = null,
             created: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
             modified: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
             var opus: String? = null,
             var dateOfCreation: String? = null,
             var dateOfPremiere: String? = null,

      @JsonManagedReference
      @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE]
       ) 
      var placeOfPremiere: PlaceEntity? = null,

      ...Other Properties...equals...hashcode...
```

Parent:

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "place")
      class PlaceEntity(
              id: String? = null,
              title: String? = null,
              created: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
              modified: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
              var name: String? = null,
              var locality: String? = null,
              var country: String? = null,

              @Embedded
              @AttributeOverrides(
                  AttributeOverride(name = "latitude", column = Column(name = "latitude")),
                  AttributeOverride(name = "longitude", column = Column(name = "longitude"))
              )
              var coordinates: CoordinatesEntity? = CoordinatesEntity(),

              @JsonBackReference
              @OneToMany(mappedBy = "placeOfPremiere")
              var relatedWorks: MutableSet<WorkEntity>? = mutableSetOf()              
              ...Other Properties...equals...hashcode...
```

The Dropdown Menu of my ThymeleafTemplate:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="places">Places</label>
                    <select th:field="*{placeOfPremiere.id}" class="form-control" id="places"
                            name="Place of Premiere">
                        <option th:value="">Select Places</option>
                        <option
                                th:each="place : ${places}"
                                th:value="${place.id}"
                                th:text="${place.title}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
               <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('placeOfPremiere')}" th:errors {placeOfPremiere}"></span>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that the `Work` entitie refers to a `Place` that doesn't exists yet. Either you mark the foreign key as `deferrable initially deferred` or you make sure that the order in which you call `persist` or `merge` is correct.

Comment: thanks for your hint. The error was caused by the th:value="" in the first option tag. Instead of null it generates a zero args Object of Place which cannot be persisted. Changing foreign key constraints was not necessary.